# How to differentiate between the session timeout by the Tomcat container and logout link press by the user?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, tomcat, httpsession

Is there a way to **differentiate between** the **session timeout** by the **Tomcat container** and **logout link press by the user**?

**EDIT1:** My **environment** details : *Java 1.8*, *Apache Tomcat 8.0.36* on *Windows Server 2012*

I have a `MyHttpSessionListener` class that implements `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`

```
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {         
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId()+" was CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId()+" was DESTROYED");
    }
}
```

and corresponding configuration declaration within the `web.xml` file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.webapp.listeners.MyHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I'm not using `Spring Security` for my webapp.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpSessionListener` will tackle it at Servlet level. Here one important question is that which Application/Web Server are you using?
You need to have a look at [SessionDeletedEvent and SessionExpiredEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-sessiondestroyedevent) 
For now have a try with [SessionDestroyedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionDestroyedEvent.html)

```
@Component
public class SessionEndedListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
    {
        for (SecurityContext securityContext : event.getSecurityContexts())
        {
            Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
            YourPrincipalClass user = (YourPrincipalClass) authentication.getPrincipal();
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

and you also need to register this in `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Updated Answer** 
After the recent edit, Now for this case you need to use

```
HttpSessionBindingListener
```

This is being called when object is removed from the session (either explicitly by `removeAttribute()` method of `HTTPSession` or by an invalidation/expire of the session).

Comment: Thanx Khan (@Freak) for replying, I'm not using the **Spring Security** for my application. Is there a way to detect the source of session timeout in plain `Servlets`? Have updated my environment details in the **EDIT1** above.

Comment: You were unclear in your question before edit and you had a tag of Spring-MVC so I thought you might be looking for some solution in Spring

Comment: @Shiva Have a look at Updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You could parse session lastAccessTime, and if it's some time ago (configured expiration time) then it expired.